# How to dynamically allocate memory for JNI object array

Tags: c, java-native-interface, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on JNI with C language. Here I have created an object array of size 4000. According to my requirements the array size has to grow dynamically. How can I allocate memory dynamically? I have tried using `malloc`. But I cannot achieve this.

Here's what I have tried:

```
OriginalArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 4000, tradeObject, NULL);
```

Comment: 'I cannot achieve this' is not a problem description.

Comment: I am trying to allocate memory first time for 20 and then i am trying to reallocate it to 40. But It is not working for me. I tried the following: `jobjectArray tradeOriginalArray*; sizeofthearray = 20; tradeOriginalArray = malloc(sizeofthearray * sizeof(jobjectArray)); sizeofthearray = 40; tradeOriginalArray = realloc(tradeOriginalArray, sizeof(jobjectArray) * sizeofthearray);`

Comment: Why do you think you need to use JNI for this?  This would be a tedious problem to solve for someone familiar with JNI using something like a Java HashSet object.  Doing this with JNI is making an extra effort to take something easy and **make** it hard.

Comment: Actually i need to return this object array to java code. Server code is return in C. So that we are using JNI. Is it possible to allocate the memory dynamically for the Object array in JNI?...

Answer (score 1):

*According to my requirements the array size has to grown dynamically.*

[You can't use an array.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> An *array* is a container object that holds a fixed number of values
>   of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array
>   is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

You have to use something other than a Java array to hold your data if its size has to change.

Or you can allocate a *new* array each time the size needs to change and copy the array elements from the old array to the new array.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way of allocating memory dynamically in JNI?
I am trying to allocate memory first time for 20 and then i am trying to reallocate it to 40. But It is not working for me.
I have tried the following: 
`jobjectArray tradeOriginalArray = NULL;
sizeofthearray = 20;
tradeOriginalArray = malloc(sizeofthearray * sizeof(jobjectArray));
sizeofthearray = 40;
tradeOriginalArray = realloc(tradeOriginalArray, sizeof(jobjectArray) *       sizeofthearray); `

Comment: Java memory management is completely separate from that provided via `malloc()`, `realloc()`, etc.

Comment: Ok. like allocating memory to pointers in C, can i allocate memory dynamically for object array in JNI?

Comment: No. Once the array is created - either in Java or in JNI using`NewObjectArray()` - its size is *fixed*.  If you want an array of a different size, you have to create a *new* one.

Comment: I need to have a dynamic object array in JNI?. Is it possible to have?.

Comment: **After creation, its length is fixed.**  You can **NOT** resize a Java array.

Comment: Before creation itself, is it possible to have an array of varible size?. My requirement is, i need to store the values into an array dynamically.